STRING_AGG alternative
Our SQL Server version does not support STRING_AGG because of the version
Our data is returned like this
enter image description here
But our requirement is to display it like this:
enter image description here
This is the code I believe would work should we have the functionality:
SELECT
        studentid,
        STRING_AGG(code, ',') AS Codes
    FROM
        testtable
    GROUP BY
        studentid;

Any help appreciated.
I tried this using the XML answers:
SELECT
      studentid,code
     = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + dbo.testtable .code 
          FROM dbo.testtable 
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM dbo.testtable  
GROUP BY StudentID
ORDER BY StudentID

This returns this which is sort of right but I need to have it only attaching the Students Codes not all the codes in the database:
updated results

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

You're not correlating you sub-query with the outer query row

Can you post sample data and expected output

You are missing the correlation in your subquery. e.g.
SELECT
      t1.studentid,
      code = STUFF((
                SELECT ',' + t2.code 
                FROM dbo.testtable  AS t2
                WHERE t2.studentid = t1.studentid -- Need this part
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM dbo.testtable AS t1   
GROUP BY t1.StudentID
ORDER BY StudentID;

Example on db<>fiddle

value('text()[1]', is slightly faster than value('.',

THankyou GarethD and also apologies for my bad etiquette on the rules Dale K
